# I want to send users of my android application a simple daily reminder, Do I have to use a push notification service or is there an alternative?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, reminders

To be a little bit more specific, I want to know if for example I wanted to teach someone how to take care of a pet, I would like my application to send them daily a reminder that they have to feed their pet or take it out for a walk. I have been reading about GCM and what i managed to understand is that you would need a server side to manage these, but that is not a resource available to me (and even if it were I would have no idea how to set it up). Would I have to set up GCM for this or is there another way to do this?

Comment: This very much depends on how large is the your reminder's option, and the scalability of it. If you have a fix number of reminder message, you might just use the answer provided by Casper, otherwise, if those message are very random and you might add some from time to time, GCM is better approach

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I'll give the alarm manager a shot see if it can fulfill my needs. Worst case scenario well GCM it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the AlarmManager : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

It enables you to do something at a certain point in the future.